# Add file sizes together with separate file inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-io, fileapi

Trying to add at least two file input sizes together. There may be more than two but always at least one and stop the form if it exceeds 15MB. Have it now where I am getting the file sizes and appending them to a div to check but appending just adds each size to the end. Tried html and that just replaces the node element. Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a5v5f5hx/)

```
<div id="fileAmt"></div>
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="i1" class="imageup" />
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="i2" class="imageup" />

$('input[type="file"]').each(function(i) {
// Get an array of the files for this input
$(this).change(function () {
    var files = $(this).get(0).files;
    // Loop through files
    for (var j = 0; file = files[j]; j++) {
        // File size, in bytes
        var size = file.size;
        $('#fileAmt').html(size);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I made an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5v5f5hx/1/) for ya.

What's happening here is that I'm resetting my file size count to 0 each time a file is added, then I go through and total it up and save it to a global variable `totalSize`. The portion you were missing was that you were assigning a value to a variable each time in your loop but you never SUMMED things up. You said "hey now the value is 100. hey now the value is 200". You didn't add the 100 and 200 together.

Does that make sense?

```
//my global variable that I will add to, not replace.
window.totalSize = 0;

$('input[type="file"]').each(function(i) {
    // Get an array of the files for this input
    $(this).change(function () {
        window.totalSize = 0;
        var files = $(this).get(0).files;
        // Loop through files
        for (var j = 0; file = files[j]; j++) {
            // File size, in bytes
            window.totalSize += file.size;   //Here is a key bit
            $('#fileAmt').html(window.totalSize);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense. I tried the fiddle but it did not seem to work?

Comment: The problem is, you are doing `$(this).get` files. There's nothing to loop through because `this` is referring to the one file input that changed NOT both.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put the size outside of the loop and append it inside.

```
$(this).change(function () {
    var files = $(this).get(0).files;
    var size = 0;
    // Loop through files
    for (var j = 0; file = files[j]; j++) {
        // File size, in bytes
        size += file.size;
    }
    $('#fileAmt').html(size);
});
```

Comment: Tried that one too and it did not work in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a5v5f5hx/